# Macos app is getting closed when there're no windows open

Tags: swift, cocoa

I used the following code to make it reopen and prevent from closing when you click on the close button.

The problem is that it just closes(the dot under the app's icon in dock disappears)

```
    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    func applicationShouldHandleReopen(_ sender: NSApplication, hasVisibleWindows flag: Bool) -> Bool {
      for window in NSApplication.shared.windows {
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
      }
      return true
    }
```

**UPDATE**

When I keep the main window open the app icon doesn't disappear from dock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [NSSupportsAutomaticTermination](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW13) to NO in your Info.plist.

Comment: Alternatively I believe one can call `NSProcessInfo.processInfo().disableAutomaticTermination` in code...?

Comment: That sounds good too. It's described in the second paragraph of the documentation I linked.

Comment: Also I think we need to ask _why_ the app is terminating automatically. It isn't usual. The English name of this key is "Application can be killed to reclaim memory or other extraordinary circumstances". The implication is that the app is making some sort of memory management mistake. Instead of putting a band-aid over it, the OP should be fixing the app's memory management.

Comment: The documentation I linked says “Primarily, the app can be terminated when it is hidden or does not have any visible windows and is not currently being used.”

Comment: Yes, but I think those are meant to be necessary, not sufficient, conditions. The wording is canny. The Info.plist key English name seems to give more of a clue. And this makes a certain sense, since otherwise `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed` and `NSSupportsAutomaticTermination` would be equivalent.

Comment: So there's a memory leak in my app? I don't know how to look for memory leaks but this definitely worked for me.

Comment: @kirqe I don't actually know what causes automatic termination; I'm just suggesting that the need to change this setting in your Info.plist might be diagnostic of a deeper issue. Use the memory gauge, perhaps, to see whether your app uses abnormal amounts of memory. Maybe it doesn't and I'm just guessing wrong.

Comment: @matt, it's just a simple json to tableview app. It uses around 65mb most of the time. Anyway, thanks for helping